# Rename the Community user on localized sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-user, localization

Renaming the Community user on the language-specific sites ([Russian SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), [Japanese SO](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), etc) would be a good thing to do as the username for the boterator doesn't seem to be localized to the site's language.

Comment: In Japanese (コミュニティ), in Russian (сообщество), in Portuguese (comunidade), That's for those of you who are as curious as I am, and here are some more because I know and you know you will pickup a few more random languages in Google translate: Zulu (umphakathi), Chinese (社区), Arabic (مجتمع), Hebrew (קהילה)..and since I love you curious guys, here is a direct link to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/af/community) ;)

Comment: It's already localized on [pt.so]: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade

Comment: I'd like to suggest also localizing a Community's description (it has no description in Russian).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I see this feature request is already satisfied. All of the localized sites have its own name (except for SO in Japanese and Русский язык SE) and description.

You can check them self:

- [ruSO Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)
- [rusSE Community](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)
- [ptSO Comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade)
- [esSO Comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad)
- [jaSO Community](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)

Community user name and description are available to edit in the site settings file. Community manager should know about it in more details. Lack of the translation for user name on some sites should be posted as FR/bugs on appropriate metas.

Comment: Maybe those names should be in Transifex?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog not sure that Transifex is the best place for this, because same language sites (like ruSO and rusSE) can’t have different names/descriptions in this case.

Comment: This was just fixed on rus.SE, and may end up fixed on ja.SO soon (if the community approves it; it seems they will probably do so.)