# Localize the username of the Community user on rus.SE and ja.SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-user, localization, international-sites

https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

This was already asked for in [Rename the Community user on localized sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252905/rename-the-community-user-on-localized-sites) and marked completed, but it wasn't implemented on these sites for some reason; this is therefore a bug with its implementation.

Comment: Google translate suggests (network) сообщество for Community. It would be helpful for you to offer a suggestion that captures the essence of the meaning and include that in your question.

Comment: Re-edited this into a bug report, as this has already been requested earlier and marked "completed" (when it clearly wasn't).

Comment: Also, to potential close voters as "site-specific": the team has stated that English-language questions about localized sites are to be asked here as the site metas only accept questions in their languages, and even without that, this is about two sites, so a close reason about "one specific site" can't apply.

Comment: Robert Cartaino says [no segregation](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/101/1797), that the English name (so it's *understood* what is meant) be followed by the translation. Some translations of languages may pose more of a challenge; it's important for people to recognize the nature of this user without having to translate names. See also:[Korean site](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14/2197). Portuguese [refers to the user as Community](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/96/4968), to avoid confusion. [Latin.SE](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/207/3647).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't really an "implementation" here - all that was done was the Community user's display name and bio was manually edited by someone on those sites. It was simply never brought up on the other two sites, so it was never done. That's not really a bug, just a lack of people caring in those places.

I've changed it on the Russian Language site to match that of Stack Overflow in Russian. I wouldn't have the slightest clue what the corresponding name would be in Japanese. That's something to bring up on SO in Japanese so they can discuss what is best and whether it makes sense to change the name.

Comment: So just to confirm - when mods change the Community user on a per-site basis, they don't have the option to 'save changes across SE' right?

Comment: Would you consider reopening? There's one more Russian site, if you're only doing one language.

Comment: @Robotnik No, because the Community user doesn't have a network account.

Comment: @Rob If you're referring to russian.SE, the English name is correct, as the site's UI is in English.

Comment: Can you please also copy over the "location" field to rus.SE, with the translation being used on ru.SO?

Comment: @animusonik, as you prefer. I don't use those sites.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog are you certain you wouldn't prefer the translation of the [meta profile for the Community user](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/%d0%94%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0) as it seems that there's a different translated version there; if not then you'd prefer that to be repaired.

Comment: @Rob That's rus.SE, not russian.SE. And they're both the same for the profiles there; you can verify this by clicking the translated versions of "main user" and "meta user".

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Use the contact link in future, if you need me to help ping again.